# Objective C stringWithCString "Method cache corrupted"

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, macos, nsstring

I am creating a method for executing shell commands. It looks like this:

```
NSString *cShellStr(NSString *command, int maxBufferSize) {
    if (maxBufferSize<1) {
        maxBufferSize = INT_MAX;
    }
    NSString *newCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ 2>&1", command];
    const char *cStrCommand = [newCommand cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    FILE *fp;
    fp = popen(cStrCommand, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to open process");
        return nil;
    }
    char *buffer = NULL;
    buffer = (char*)malloc(4);
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to allocate memory");
        return nil;
    }
    while (!feof(fp)) {
        buffer = realloc(buffer, sizeof(buffer)+1);
        sprintf(buffer, "%s%c", buffer, fgetc(fp));
    }
    NSString *ret = [NSString stringWithCString:buffer encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    fclose(fp);
    free(buffer);
    return ret;
}
```

However, it *usually* (strangely not always) gets this error at `[NSString stringWithCString:buffer encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]`:

```
objc[33674]: Method cache corrupted. This may be a message to an invalid object, or a memory error somewhere else.
objc[33674]: receiver 0x7fff7d62aec0, SEL 0x7fff99ac69f5, isa 0x7fff7d62aee8, cache 0x7fff7d62aef8, buckets 0x100200780, mask 0x3, occupied 0x2, wrap bucket 0x100200780
objc[33674]: receiver 0 bytes, buckets 64 bytes
objc[33674]: selector 'class'
objc[33674]: isa 'NSString'
objc[33674]: Method cache corrupted.
objc[33674]: Method cache corrupted. This may be a message to an invalid object, or a memory error somewhere else.
objc[33674]: receiver 0x7fff7d62aec0, SEL 0x7fff99aea2d4, isa 0x7fff7d62aee8, cache 0x7fff7d62aef8, buckets 0x100200780, mask 0x3, occupied 0x2, wrap bucket 0x100200780
objc[33674]: receiver 0 bytes, buckets 64 bytes
objc[33674]: selector 'stringWithCString:encoding:'
objc[33674]: isa 'NSString'
objc[33674]: Method cache corrupted.
```

I have stepped through it with lldb and confirmed that there are no other errors and that `buffer` contains exactly the text I would expect. Am I incorrectly using `stringWithCString`?

Extra info:
Xcode version:
[image: xcode info]

Laptop info:
[image: laptop info]

Clang version:

```
Apple LLVM version 
6.0 (clang-600.0.51) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: May be not an actual issue, but `sizeof(buffer)+1` is /constant/.

Comment: Yep, any time you do `sizeof` a `char*` it's pretty certain to be a bug.  It might kinda work out in this case, but not if you make `buffer` larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (!feof(fp)) {
    buffer = realloc(buffer, sizeof(buffer)+1);
    sprintf(buffer, "%s%c", buffer, fgetc(fp));
}
```

This loop should be rewritten as:

```
size_t len = 0, cap = 4;
buffer = malloc(cap); // TODO check NULL
int c;
while (EOF != (c = fgetc(fp))) {
    if (len >= cap) {
        cap += cap;
        buffer = realloc(buffer, cap); // TODO check NULL
    }
    buffer[len++] = c;
}
// check feof/ferror
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        sprintf(buffer, "%s%c", buffer, fgetc(fp));
```

This is undefined behaviour because you are using buffer twice. Anything could go wrong, and lucky for you, it does. I'm saying "lucky for you" because with a bit of bad luck it would only go wrong in the hand of customers.

I didn't watch out; the issue that user3125367 found is ten times worse.

Comment: This was useful but not the problem. What user3125367 found was really messing things up. I should fix this too, though.